# Split-apply-combine with function that returns multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I need to apply `myfun` to subsets of a dataframe and include the results as new columns in the dataframe returned. In the old days, I used `ddply`. But in `dplyr`, I believe `summarise` is used for that, like this:

```
myfun<- function(x,y) {
  df<- data.frame( a= mean(x)*mean(y), b= mean(x)-mean(y) )           
  return (df)
}

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(a = myfun(cyl,disp)$a, b = myfun(cyl,disp)$b)
```

The above code works, but the `myfun` I'll be using is computationally very expensive, so I want it to be called *only once* rather than separately for the `a` and `b` columns. Is there a way to do that in `dplyr`?

Comment: Is `myfun` the actual function you intend to use? Because in this case, I don't see the point of creating a data frame within the function when you only want to return 2 numbers anyway. `mtcars %>%  group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(a = mean(cyl)*mean(disp), b = mean(cyl) - mean(disp))` should return the same result, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The `myfun` I'll be using is computationally very expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function returns a data frame, you can call your function within `group_by %>% do` which applies the function to each individual group and *rbind* the returned data frame together:

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(myfun(.$cyl, .$disp))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl         a         b
#  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#1     4  420.5455 -101.1364
#2     6 1099.8857 -177.3143
#3     8 2824.8000 -345.1000
```

Comment: If `myfun` returns multiple rows, as well as columns, use `do(nested col = myfun(3, .$disp)) %>% tidyr::unnest()`.

Answer (score 3):

`do` is not necessarily going to improve the speed. In this post, I am going to introduce a way to design a function performing the same task, and then do a benchmarking to compare the performance of each method.

Here is an alternative way to define the function.

```
myfun2 <- function(dt, x, y){
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)

  dt2 <- dt %>%
    summarise(a = mean(!!x) * mean(!!y), b = mean(!!x) - mean(!!y))
  return(dt2)
}
```

Notice that the first argument of `myfun2` is `dt`, which is the input data frame. By doing this, `myfun2` can successfully implement as a part of the pipe operation.

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  myfun2(x = cyl, y = disp)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
    cyl         a         b
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     4  420.5455 -101.1364
2     6 1099.8857 -177.3143
3     8 2824.8000 -345.1000
```

By doing this, we don't have to call `my_fun` each time when we want to create a new column. So this method is probably more efficient than `my_fun`.

Here is a comparison of the performance using the `microbenchmark`. The methods I compared are listed as follows. I ran the simulation 1000 times.

```
m1: OP's original way to apply `myfun`  
m2: Psidom's method, using `do`to apply `myfun`.  
m3: My approach, using `myfun2`  
m4: Using `do` to apply `myfun2`  
m5: Z.Lin's suggestion, directly calculating the values without defining a function.
m6: akrun's `data.table` approach with `myfun`
```

Here is the code for benchmarking.

```
microbenchmark(m1 = (mtcars %>%
                       group_by(cyl) %>%
                       summarise(a = myfun(cyl, disp)$a, b = myfun(cyl, disp)$b)),
               m2 = (mtcars %>% 
                       group_by(cyl) %>% 
                       do(myfun(.$cyl, .$disp))),
               m3 = (mtcars %>%
                       group_by(cyl) %>%
                       myfun2(x = cyl, y = disp)),
               m4 = (mtcars %>%
                       group_by(cyl) %>%
                       do(myfun2(., x = cyl, y = disp))),
               m5 = (mtcars %>% 
                       group_by(cyl) %>% 
                       summarise(a = mean(cyl) * mean(disp), b = mean(cyl) - mean(disp))),
               m6 = (as.data.table(mtcars)[, myfun(cyl, disp), cyl]),
               times = 1000)
```

And here is the result of benchmarking.

```
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
   m1  7.058227  7.692654  9.429765  8.375190 10.570663  28.730059  1000
   m2  8.559296  9.381996 11.643645 10.500100 13.229285  27.585654  1000
   m3  6.817031  7.445683  9.423832  8.085241 10.415104 193.878337  1000
   m4 21.787298 23.995279 28.920262 26.922683 31.673820 177.004151  1000
   m5  5.337132  5.785528  7.120589  6.223339  7.810686  23.231274  1000
   m6  1.320812  1.540199  1.919222  1.640270  1.935352   7.622732  1000
```

The result shows that the `do` method (`m2` and `m4`) are actually slower than their counterparts(`m1` and `m3`). In this situation, applying `myfun` (`m1`) and `myfun2` (`m3`) is faster than using `do`. `myfun2` (`m3`) is slighly faster than `myfun` (`m1`). However, without defining any functions (`m5`) is actually faster than all the function-defined method (`m1` to `m4`), suggesting that for this particular case, there is actually no need to define a fucntion. Finally, if there is no need to stay in `tidyverse`, or the size of the dataset is enormous. We can consider the `data.table` approach (`m6`), which is a lot faster than all the `tidyverse` solutions listed here.

Comment: I think the `group_by` can also be incldued inside the functions and then just call `myfun(mtcars)`

Comment: Yes, we can add an argument to specify which column is for group_by.

Comment: Very interesting, but `do` does what I wanted of calling my time-consuming `myfun` only once.

Comment: do is definitely a valid solution. But I want to show that it could be worthy of re-designing the function without using do to achieve the task.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mtcars)[, myfun(cyl, disp), cyl] 
#    cyl         a         b
#1:   6 1099.8857 -177.3143
#2:   4  420.5455 -101.1364
#3:   8 2824.8000 -345.1000
```